# What Spanish term (or terms) work best to describe a glass jar as used for coffee, jam, etc?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

A bit earlier [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/spanish-language-and-usage) I mentioned that I needed to buy a new jar of coffee, but that I didn't know how to express that in Spanish.

I want to know a good Spanish word for "jar" in the sense of a glass container with a lid that is opened and closed by a twisting action.

[image: jar of coffee]
<sup>The original jar of instant coffee that inspired the question</sup>

[image: more jars]
Some more jars I found about the place, as an added bonus they all have label in exotic languages: Armenian, Georgian,

There seems to be a Spanish cognate of "jar" in "jarro" but to me that doesn't have the sense of "jar" that I'm looking for, though it might for some of the other senses of "jar" (senses I never use in Australian English at any rate).

Other words that came all seemed wrong in one way or another:

- "tarro" to me is a glass beer mug in Mexico
- "lata" to me is a metallic can or tin
- "envase" is probably OK but it feels more generic like "packaging"
- "bote" I think I've only come across meaning something more like "basket" but it's not really in my vocabulary

**Is any one of these words the most accurate, or is there a word we overlooked, or will it vary from region to region?**

There is a Wikipedia page on jars, but it does not link to a Spanish equivalent.

Comment: I agree that *tarro cafe* would be coffee mug.  *Bote de cafe* may work, since *bote de mermelada* means, roughly, "jelly jar"-- but the "boat of jelly" makes me take pause.  Interesting question! +1

Comment: You shouldn't be buying your coffee in a jar in the first place. The good coffee always comes in a bag. :)

Comment: Yeah where I am now getting real coffee is actually easy. But we don't have a coffee machine and I'm too lazy to make it in a jezve, which I would only mess up anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't add nothing unless it's necessary.

Comment: You don't need to specify, really. you can say i'm going to buy coffee =)

Comment: @David: But saying "I need to buy a coffee" is different to saying "I need to buy a jar of coffee". I could edit into the question "when it's necessary to distinguish" but it seems silly to interpret it any other way. It's a question about "word for jar" not about "how to say I'm going to buy coffee" (-:

Comment: @Richard: note that *<algo> café* means "brown <something>", so "tarro café" is "brown jar". You have to say "tarro **de** café" for "coffee jar".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It actually depends on the region in which you are. As Omar said, *frasco* is quite understandable by all means with a proper context, but without it it can be interpreted differently.

As the RAE definition states, *frasco* is mainly a glass made of some material, it can be glass, porcelain or whatever (Glass and porcelain are the most common interpretations for the word.

RAE:

> > **[Frasco.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=frasco)**
>
> (Del germ. *flaskô, funda de mimbres para una botella, botella; cf. a.
>   al. ant. flasca, nórd. flaska).
>
> 1. m. Vaso de cuello recogido, hecho de vidrio u otra materia, que sirve para contener líquidos, sustancias en polvo, comprimidos, etc.
> 2. m. Vaso hecho regularmente de cuerno, en que se llevaba la pólvora para cargar la escopeta.
> 3. m. Contenido de un frasco.
>
> ~ cuentagotas.
>
> 1. m. frasco que por la forma de su gollete y de su tapón sirve para verter gota a gota su contenido.
>
> ~ de mercurio.
>
> 1. m. Peso de tres arrobas de mercurio, que es la cabida de los antiguos frascos de hierro usados como envase en Almadén, en España.

Now about regionalisms these are the ones I personally know.  <sup>I am a native Colombian</sup>

**Colombia**

*Tarro* and *Frasco* are equally used and have a wide variety of meaning according to context. Usually glass, porcelain or metal.

We also use *Jarrón*, but this is a bit different, usually used for flowers, or for more heavy things, bigger things. Usually made of porcelain, but can be of glass as well; not metal.

*Bote* can also be used, but *bote* is more made of plastic and much bigger. Bigger than *Jarrón* even. Although depending on context can also be interpreted as the same size, but not the same material.

**Chile** | **Argentina**

*Tarro* is more understood as metal. *Frasco* would be the proper usage as it is understood as made from glass.

**Ecuador**

*Tarro* is widely used for a receptacle made of glass. *Frasco* is rarely used to say it, not to say awkward when used.

**Spain**

*Tarro* is more used than *frasco*, as *tarro* is interpreted as being made from glass. And usually (in Spain) the cofee is in glass, or metal containers (depends on region, in Colombia most are of metal or in plastic bags.)

**Panama**

*Tarro* and *frasco* are used, sometimes *envase* but it really is dependent on context, as for an industrial use, or using a *frasco* de café vacío for something else.

**Mexico**

*Tarro* is more interpreted as a pint or glass of beer, or some other drink. *Frasco* is more interpreted for this use. *Bote* is seldom used for this context.

**Central America**

*Bote* can be understood for coffee more widely than in other regions. Nevertheless *frasco* is used as well.

Now, **envase** is more literal to container and more general. **Lata** is almost always made of metal (I don't know how it is interpreted in Equatorial guinea or the Philippines, but I think it's safe to assume they interpret it the same way as us Latin Americans)

*Bote* really depends on the region, as said in Central America it is more used than in other regions.

To make a safe bet use *frasco* or *tarro*. *Frasco* for a small recipient or container, and *tarro* for a bigger one specially if it is made of metal. *Frasco* is more glass, and *tarro* more metal.

Comment: You can add "Argentina" to your "Chile" entry, we coincide in that. "Bote" is definitely not used here in that sense.

Comment: In addition _lata_ in Filipino/Tagalog directly corresponds to "metal cans" as in "canned goods" while _bote_ is for glass bottles.

Comment: I've heard that usage in Spain and Latin America as well, Eduardo.

Answer (score 14):

The proper Spanish term for a jar would be a `frasco`, like in:

> Voy a comprar un frasco de café.

Depending on the region, `bote de café` could be acceptable.

[RAE reference to 'frasco'](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=frasco)

Comment: This seems good. I didn't know this word from Mexico and my Larousse Gran Diccionario translates it as *bottle* but Google Image Search does indeed return lots of glass jar pictures.

Comment: Also "tarro" ("frasco" synonym)

Comment: @JuanManuel: but "tarro", at least here in Chile, means a can, or something like a metal jar, but always made out of some sort of metal.

Comment: frasco means flask

Comment: @Nicólas A tarro in Spain is usually made of glass. If you see the definition of Tarro at RAE website it says it's made of glass or porcelain.

Answer (score 3):

In Texas I hear "frasco" mostly for this type of container.  "Lata," to my knowledge, is always made of some type of metal.

One can put almost anything inside a "frasco."

Answer (score 2):

In Spain, a *tarro* is almost always made of glass. In my opinion, is the best word (again, in Spain), to refer to "a glass container with a lid that is opened and closed by a twisting action".

*Frasco* is usually a small *tarro*, but can be made of other material. Also, the double *r* in *tarro* provides a sense of strong and durability (and lots of *tarros* has a thick glass). *Frasco* is usually more delicate and elegant (that's why perfumes comes in *frascos*, despite they are made of glass and follow your initial definition).

*Lata* is always made of metal. The only exceptions are items that have been common and made of metal for years but recently there are plastic versions (*lata de gasolina* comes to my mind).

Answer (score 0):

Pero tarro en España y frasco en español, significa, al menos para los cubanos, que la boca es pequeña, que es lo que tiene una botella, por ejemplo.
Cuando echas agua o jugos para servirla a la mesa, es usualmente en una jarra, que su boca es ancha.
Aquí puedes especificar del material en que está hecho. Por ejemplo:

- La jarra de cristal
- La jarra de metal

Es como un sinónimo de la palabra *pitcher* en inglés. Por ejemplo: su boca es ancha como la de una jarra.